# sqlite3_exec != SQLITE_OK

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Anybody help me please.
I can't insert the data to sqlite.

the output is "News added failed".

Note :
 - The database is already created.
 - News is an object
I just think that the problem is in this function.
Could you tell me whats wrong with my code?
Thanks.

```
- (void)addNews:(NSString *)content_caption content_date:(NSString *)content_date content_desk:(NSString *)content_desk content_id:(NSString *)content_id content_img:(NSString *)content_img content_type:(NSString *)content_type content_web_url:(NSString *)content_web_url{


char *error;
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *inserStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO dBase(CONTENT_CAPTION,CONTENT_DATE, CONTENT_DESK, CONTENT_ID, CONTENT_IMG, CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_WEB_URL) values (\'%@\',\'%@\',\'%@\',\'%@\',\'%@\',\'%@\',\'%@\')",content_caption, content_date, content_desk, content_id, content_img, content_type ,content_web_url];

    const char *insert_stmt = [inserStmt UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_exec(database, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"News added");

        News *news = [[News alloc]init];

        [news setContent_caption:content_caption];
        [news setContent_date:content_date];
        [news setContent_desk:content_desk];
        [news setContent_id:content_id];
        [news setContent_img:content_img];
        [news setContent_type:content_type];
        [news setContent_web_url:content_web_url];

        [arrayOfNews addObject:news];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"News added failed");
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

}

Comment: I bet the database is in the app bundle... Google "iOS can't write file in app bundle", you will see a lot of dupes.

Comment: could you give the right solution for me please? @H2CO3

Comment: I did - google that phrase and you'll see it.

Comment: this is not the same question. @V-Xtreme Just check it first.

Comment: Do yourself a big favor and get into the habit off logging [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) when you get a bad return code.

Comment: @Template09: I have checked already , I am saying that this is  same type of problem .

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
    #define SQLITE_TRANSIENT   ((sqlite3_destructor_type)-1)

    const char *insertSql;
    insertSql = nil;
    insertSql = "INSERT INTO dBase(CONTENT_CAPTION,CONTENT_DATE, CONTENT_DESK, CONTENT_ID, CONTENT_IMG, CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_WEB_URL) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 1, [content_caption UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 2, [content_date UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 3, [content_desk UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 4, [content_id UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 5, [content_img UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 6, [content_type UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 7, [content_web_url UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set path of your database . Do like this

// Setting path

```
  NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
   databasepath =[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"yourDatabase"];
 NSFileManager *fn=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSError *error;
 BOOL success=[fn fileExistsAtPath:databasepath];
   if(!success) {
           NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"quizdb"];
    success = [fn copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:databasepath error:&error];
}
```

//Next you have to insert as follows

```
 sqlite3_stmt *statement;
 const char *dbpath=[databasepath UTF8String];
 if(sqlite3_open(dbpath,&contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
 {
    const char *sqlStatement = "insert into dBase(CONTENT_CAPTION,CONTENT_DATE, CONTENT_DESK, CONTENT_ID, CONTENT_IMG, CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_WEB_URL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB,sqlStatement,-1,&statement,NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [content_caption UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);      
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [content_date UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3 ,[content_desk UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [content_id UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [content_img UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [content_type UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 7, [content_web_url UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);           
    }
    if (sqlite3_step(statement)!= SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Save Error:%s",sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"success");

        sqlite3_reset(statement);
               }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
     sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```

Hope it will helps you..